# Switching from Blueprint to Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blueprint-css

I'm replacing Blueprint with Twitter Bootstrap in a Rails 3.1 application. I've followed the example in the Railscast and I have it working in that example. However, when I try to put it into my application the collapse functionality in the navbar doesn't work. When I click on it nothing happens.

I'm using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

I've removed the Blueprint folder from the stylesheets directory. I've also removed any Blueprint javascripts from the javascripts directory. I've cleared any compiled versions from the Public/Assets directory.  I've also cleared my tmp directory. Restarted my server and for some reason the collapse functionality still doesn't work.

Has anyone else done this? Any ideas on what I should try next?

Comment: Did you include jQuery and the required js files?

Comment: Application.js shows the following:

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .

Comment: I seem to be getting a javascript error.

Error: $("body").on is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:3000/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1
Line: 92

Comment: You need to include jQuery "first" than the bootstraps js files, you can try including google's hosted jQuery script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You also might have an old version of Jquery installed, .on is not supported before, I think 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

After debugging and Googling for an answer I found that I needed to update jquery-rails to 1.0.18

Once I did that everything worked fine.