# link_to renders incorrectly after moving to bootstrap-sass from blueprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

May seem related to [Switching from Blueprint to Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9639657/1106877) but that didn't fix my issue.

I have cleaned up all blueprint references, cleared cache & temp, gems (bootstrap-sass and jquery) are installed, and restarted the server.

All my link_to statements render with the reference next to my text. Also my bulleted menu content stands vertical as opposed to being horizontal.

This is the code from my pre-compiled layouts.css.scss that should make my header menu lie flat and more to the right.

Help.

```
/* line 179, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bootstrap-sass- 
2.0.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navbar.scss */
.navbar .nav.pull-right { float: right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

K. Turns out that even after you delete blueprint files from app/assets/stylesheets, there still a few not-so-obvious that also need to be removed.

Under the same directory (app/asset/stylesheets) you will find two folders named: "plugins" and "src" (i.e. if you previously had blueprint installed). REMOVE THEM and bootstrap assets will kick in.